# Is there a way to overcome 401 unauthorized error in React, while trying to access data from Rapidapi.com?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux

I am facing the problem of unauthorized 401. Done everything mentally possible, so posting it here with code and result pics. The data when accessed like this retrieves data without problem.

```js
var axios = require("axios").default;

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/stats',
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'key'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

But when I try to access it via the code, it does not. please have a look at the code.

index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import App from "./App";
import store from "./app/store";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

ReactDom.render(
  <Router>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

CryptoApi.js

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const cryptoApiHeaders = {
  "x-rapidapi-host": "coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com",
  "x-rapidapi-key": "key",
};

const baseUrl = "https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com";

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, header: cryptoApiHeaders });

export const cryptoApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "cryptoApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCryptos: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest("/coins"),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetCryptosQuery } = cryptoApi;
```

store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { cryptoApi } from "../services/cryptoApi";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [cryptoApi.reducerPath]: cryptoApi.reducer,
  },
});
```

Homepage.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import millify from "millify";
import { Typography, Row, Col, Statistic } from "antd";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { useGetCryptosQuery } from "../services/cryptoApi";

const { Title } = Typography;

const Homepage = () => {
  const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptosQuery();
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <>
      <Title level={2} className="heading">
        Global Crypto Stats
      </Title>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}>
          <Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value="5" />
          <Statistic title="Total Exchanges" value="5" />
          <Statistic title="Total Market Cap" value="5" />
          <Statistic title="Total 24h Voulume" value="5" />
          <Statistic title="Total Markets" value="5" />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

Errors in console: [image: console]

Thank you.

Comment: You probably should not post your key here

Comment: deleting it right now. thanks. i was desperate.

Answer (score 1):

Quite interesting, I believe you're already subscribed to API. Generally, a 410 code indicates a lack of authentication.

You can try this in CryptoApi.js file

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const cryptoApiHeaders = {
  "x-rapidapi-host": "coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com",
  "x-rapidapi-key": "key",
};

const baseUrl = "https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/stats";

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, header: cryptoApiHeaders });

export const cryptoApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "cryptoApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCryptos: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest("/coins"),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetCryptosQuery } = cryptoApi;
```

If it still doesn't work, you can always reach out to the RapidAPI support team at support@rapidapi.com

Answer (score 1):

On your CryptoApi.js file, there's a typo

*const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, **header**: cryptoApiHeaders });*

should be *'headers: ...'*

That should fix the 401 issue.